# Conditionally stop current or all cell executions

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a complex flow split into multiple cells that can be run optionally or all at once.

However, when they are run all at once, I need a way to

- exit from current cell (ideally with a message)
- prevent other cells in queue to be executed

Additionally, is this possible?

- re-run current cell
- re-run current cell and continue execution flow

Is there a line magic or another way that achieves that?